# Swift: How to convert a list of String to a list of CGPoint?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am a complete newbie to Swift and didn't found anything on the web. How do I convert a string formatted this way:

```
let str:String = "0,0 624,0 624,-48 672,-48 672,192"
```

to an array of CGPoint's ?

Comment: Break it down into problems: parse the string into string parts, convert those parts to numbers, then convert those to CGPoint

Comment: I'm curious where you got these awfully formatted strings from

Comment: @AMomchilov: It's from a *.tmx file, a tile map formatted in xml.

Comment: Why not use a library?

Comment: I am using JSTileMap library, but the polygon lines are exported like this and the library just provides a dictionary to read those properties.

Comment: I also would prefer to have a clearly structured type which parse those properties. But this is not the case for JSTileMap as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution uses the `CGPointFromString` function provided by iOS.

```
import UIKit

let res = str
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .map { CGPointFromString("{\($0)}") }
```

Comment: Thanks - also a very sexy alternative :-) !

Comment: @appzYourLife You're a roll!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, something like this?

```
let str:String = "0,0 624,0 624,-48 672,-48 672,192"

let pointsStringArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var points = [CGPoint]()
for pointString in pointsStringArray {
    let xAndY = pointString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let xString = xAndY[0]
    let yString = xAndY[1]
    let x = Double(xString)!
    let y = Double(yString)!
    let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    points.append(point)
}
print(points)
```

It's unsafe, of course, and doesn't handle all conditions. But this should take you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! A very good starting point, exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more functional way. Needs error checking added.

```
import Foundation

let str = "0,0 624,0 624,-48 672,-48 672,192"

let pointStrings = str.characters //get the character view
                .split{$0 == " "} //split the pairs by spaces
                .map(String.init) //convert the character views to new Strings

let points : [CGPoint] = pointStrings.reduce([]){ //reduce into a new array
                    let pointStringPair = $1.characters
                                            .split{$0 == ","} //split pairs by commas
                                            .map(String.init) //convert the character views to new Strings 
                    let x = CGFloat(Float(pointStringPair[0])!) //get the x
                    let y = CGFloat(Float(pointStringPair[1])!) //get the y
                    return $0 + [CGPoint(x: x, y: y)] //append the new point to the accumulator
                }
print(points)
```

Comment: Very nice :-) ! Thank you.

Comment: Remember to error handle. The splits can break with bad formatting, the strings might not be interpretable by the `Int` initializer, etc.